# Run task before applying plugin build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to run a task before applying a plugin in a build.gradle file?

Say I have the following code:

```
apply plugin: 'my-plugin'

task myTask(type: Exec) {

}
```

How do I ensure `myTask` runs before `my-plugin` is applied?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the actual problem you want to solve? This seems to me like a typical [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Add the plugin in `plugins{}` block but don't apply it,                                                              `Plugins { id 'my-plugin' apply false }` but anyway the problem isn't so obvious, Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I need a task to run before a plugin but the plugin is in an external package so I can't update the plugin code.  What I ended up doing is executing the task immediately before the plugin was applied.  I think the proper solution would be to update the plugin task to depend on my task but I can't do that in this case since I can't update the plugin code.